# Why won't my session time out log out not work?

Tags: php, session-timeout

It should logout after 20 mins of inactivity but it logs out after 3-4 seconds, I don't know where I'm going wrong. I know other questions are out there but I've looked and can't find fix.

```
<?php

session_start();
if ((isset($_SESSION['Username']) && $_SESSION['Username'] != "") || (isset($_SESSION['uID']) && $_SESSION['uID'] != "") || (isset($_SESSION['Password']) && $_SESSION['Password'] != "")) { 

$selectUsers = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uID='{$_SESSION['uID']}'");
$getRow = $selectUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($getRow['lasthit'] == time()+20*60) {
session_destroy();
session_unset();
$PDO->query("UPDATE `users` SET online=0 WHERE uID='{$_SESSION['uID']}'");
header("Refresh:3; URL=login.php");
} else {
$updateLastHit = $PDO->query("UPDATE `users` SET lasthit=NOW() WHERE uID='{$_SESSION['uID']}'");    
}  


} else {
header("Refresh:3; URL=login.php");
echo '<p class="error">You need to login, you are being redirected to login page.</p>';
endPage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Your post has been edited. Stack Overflow has syntax highlighting for a reason.

Comment: Use this; $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (20 * 60) ;

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, thanks for that. I'm sorry!

Comment: UPDATE queries don't return results, you can't use `fetch()` with them.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry it doesn't work still any other ideas?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought it would work if I changed but didn't.

Comment: What did you change? You need to do a `SELECT` to get the old value of `lastHit` _before_ you update it.

Comment: @Barmar, will try it one sec.

Comment: @Barmar, Nope that doesn't work either.

Comment: can you add the new code you tried to your question?

Comment: @Barmar, added new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($getRow['lasthit'] == time()+20*60) {
```

should be:

```
if ($getRow['lasthit'] < time()-20*60) {
```

You're looking for an exact match, and you're also adding instead of subtracting.

Change your SELECT query to:

```
$selectUsers = $PDO->query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lasthit) lasthit FROM `users` WHERE uID='{$_SESSION['uID']}'");
```

so that it will return an integer, not a timestamp, which you can compare with PHP's `now()`.

Comment: What datatype is `lasthit`? You're treating it as `int`, that won't work if it's actually `datetime`.

Comment: Datatype is TimeStamp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$getRow['lasthit']` contains the correct value, I think that you're using the wrong formula here:

```
if ($getRow['lasthit'] <  time()+20*60) {
```

With the current code, it will always return true since time() will return a value higher than `$getRow['lasthit']`. This formula should work:

```
if ((time() - $getRow['lasthit']) >  20*60) {
```

Comment: Have you verified if `$getRow['lasthit']` contains the correct value? Also, check if both time() and $getRow['lasthit'] returns integer numbers.